# Handling server side validation with Ember Data

Tags: validation, ember.js, server-side, ember-data

I'm having trouble handling server side validations with Ember and Ember Data.

When a validation error occurs, the API returns the code 422. Ember data then triggers the `becameInvalid` callback on the model.

From here, I'm not sure what's the best way to handle the errors I'm getting, and how to make them bubble up to the view.

```
App.Challenge = DS.Model.extend Ember.Validations,
    title: attr('string')
    summary: attr('string')
    # other attributes

    becameInvalid: (errors) ->
        # is it the place where I should handle the errors?
        # how would I make the errors bubble up to the view here?
```

I have 2 issues.

- I'm not sure if `becameInvalid` is the place to handle the errors, and if it is, how to make the errors display in the view
- In `becameInvalid`, `@get('isValid')` returns `true`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it the place where I should handle the errors?

Yes. But you might not need to do anything at all. Ember-data expects your api to have included any validation errors in it's json response. That errors object is passed to the `becameInvalid` hook and also saved as a property `errors` on the model. So if all you want to do is display the errors in your view, it might be enough to do something like:

```
{{input value=firstName}}<p class="inline-help">{{errors.firstName}}</p>
```

See: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L50-L61

> In becameInvalid, @get('isValid') returns true, which doesn't make sense to me

Agreed that's weird. I think it's a bindings thing, like the becameInvalid hook is running before bindings have updated.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I don't have to do anything. My issue is that I'm using ember-validations and it's setting the errors within the `validationErrors` object, which makes handling the errors more complicated than it should be. I'll try another plugin which sets the errors on the `errors` object directly. Thanks.