# How to handle server side validation in Ember-Data 1.0.0

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.2.0 and the latest Ember Data Beta and wonder, how to handle server side errors (from API calls).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434350/handling-server-side-validation-with-ember-data) is quite similar, but it doesn't work.

At first, the `becameInvalid` method doesn't triggered. I'm using [ember-validations](https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations) (do I have to?)

My API sends an 422 status code and responses like that:

```
{"errors":{"name":["has already been taken"],"initial":["has already been taken"]}}
```

**model.js**

```
Docket.Customer = DS.Model.extend( Ember.Validations, {
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  initial:     DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  validations: {
    name: {
      presence: true
    }
  },
  becameError: function() {
    alert('there was an error!');
  },
  becameInvalid: function(errors) {
    alert("Record was invalid because: " + errors);
  }
});
```

**controller.js**

```
Docket.OrganizationCustomersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  actions: {

    save: function () {
      var customer = this.store.createRecord('customer');
      customer.set('name', this.get('name'));
      customer.set('initial', this.get('initial'));
      customer.set('description', this.get('description'));

      customer.save().then(function() {
        console.log('jeah')
      }, function() {
        console.log('nooo')
      });

    }

  }

});
```

The `becameError` method gets fired, but the `becameInvalid` method doesn't.

The second problem: even if the error is triggered, Ember.js adds the new record to the DOM. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors json is ok, I think you are using the `DS.RESTAdapter`, and it doesn't implement the `becameInvalid` based in json with errors.

Just `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` have implemented in the moment, so I recommend you to change your adapter configuration to:

```
Docket.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't change anything

Comment: Do you have an idea for my second problem?

Comment: About the becameInvalid just updating to `ActiveModelAdapter` worked in my tests. About the second problem, ember data is considering records in isInvalid state, you can use a workaround to filter only valid datas, give a look in [that](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Q7haA/) fiddle

Comment: But this create a not cool UI effect, the comment appears in the comment list, and when it's setted to invalid, then is removed.

Comment: OK. Than I have to include other validation methods to prevent creating faulty records

Comment: OK, `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` does work now, but how can I prevent now to create the record if this error raises?

Comment: In truth your record isn't saved (persisted in the server and with a id) but still appear in the customers list because, when you do `this.store.find('customer')` is returned a `RecordArray` with all customers, and any new customer created by `this.store.createRecord('customer')` will be listed independently of your current state: loaded, saved, invalid. So you will need to filter using `this.store.filter('customer', function(customer) { return customer.get('isValid') })` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Makes sense :) When I'm using the filter method, I don't get any records. I tried to debug with `return this.store.filter('customer', function(customer) { console.log(customer); return customer.get('isValid') })` and I get no messages in my console. It works for new records, but the ones already stored in the database doesn't get queried.

Comment: Ah, I see, I updated my code according to your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20402830/1184904. But unfortunately, the wrong record returns `isValid` as `true`

Comment: I understand, these methods are confuse :). The filter method just filter the local records in the store. And when the store is populated, using `find` for example, all filters are updated, so you need to use `model: function() { this.store.find('customer'); return this.store.filter('customer', ...) }` to work

Comment: Do you looked this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Q7haA/, in the model method have the correct implementation with find and filter.

Comment: Strange, I always get `true`. When I inspect the object, `currentState.isValid` actually is false and the `stateName` is `root.loaded.created.invalid`. I don't get it... But I can check the `id` because its not set when its invalid (right?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42606/discussion-between-slevin-and-marcio-rodrigues-correa-junior)

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep DS.RestAdapter, you can override its ajaxError method with the one from ActiveModelAdapter.

As for today the code, slightly adapted because some dependencies are needed, would be :

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    // ... your own customizations,
    ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
        var error = this._super(jqXHR);

        if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
            var response = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText),
                errors = {};

            if (response.errors !== undefined) {
                var jsonErrors = response.errors;

                Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach(Ember.keys(jsonErrors), function(key) {
                    errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key];
                });
            }

            return new DS.InvalidError(errors);
        } else {
            return error;
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously you have a chance here to adapt to your backend specifics: HTTP code (422 is not a standard one) and format.

Source :
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-handle-failure-to-save-on-server/3789