# Difference between find() and filter(function(){return true;}) in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a simple restaurant menu. And I need to filter list of dishes accordingly to the category in which we are now in current moment. The problem is in a strange behaviour of a `this.store.filter(...)` method. It doesn't return anything...

I want to use it like this:

```
App.DishRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (param) {
    return this.store.filter('dish', function(dish) {
      return dish.get('category_id') == param.category_id;
    });
  }
});
```

but for the test purpose I'm using `this.store.filter('dish', function() {return true;});` in my example here http://jsbin.com/AcoHeNA/43/.

Please review the code and tell me what am I doing wrong or show me the way I should filter the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`store.filter` doesn't query the server, it just filter the already loaded data in the store. In your case because you don't load data in any moment, the filter will return a empty result. You can fix it calling `this.store.find('dish');` to load data from the server, so any `filter('dish', ...)` will be updated.

```
App.DishRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (param) {
    console.log(param.dish_id);

    // pre load the data
    this.store.find('dish');
    // filter the prefetch data, when update the filter when new data are loaded
    return this.store.filter('dish', function(){return true;});    
  }
});
```

This is the updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/akeJOTah/1/edit

This is an overview of the most used store methods:

1. store.find('dish') => send a request with /dishes
2. store.find('dish', 1) => send a request with /dishes/1
3. store.find('dish', { name: 'some' }) => send a request with /dishes?name=some
4. store.filter('dish', function() { ... }) => client side filtering, don't send a request, just filter the data present in the store
5. store.filter('dish', function() { ... }, { foo: 'bar' }) => run the find with query (item 3) and perform a client side filtering
6. store.all('dish') => don't send request, just get all the data loaded in the store